# MySQL SQL how to achieve this output? selecting a column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello is there a way how to achieve my expected output below using those tables below? I alredy have a sql querty but it only returns

```
Products table

    id              name
    1               sample1
    2               sample2
    3               sample3

product_style table

    product_id      style_id
       1                1
       1                2
       1                3

schools table

    id              name
    1               school1
    2               school2
    3               school3

style table

    id              school_id       name   
    1                   1           style1
    2                   1           style2
    3                   2           style3
    4                   2           style4
    5                   57          style57

school_products table

    school_id       product_id  
      1                 1
      1                 2
      1                 3
```

I want to select the column style_name in style table

```
SELECT from prodcuts.name, style.name
FROM school_products
LEFT JOIN products on school_products.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN schools on school_products.id = schools.id
LEFT JOIN styles on school_products.id = styles.schools_id
WHERE schools.id = 57
```

my current query output is

```
products.name       style.name
    sample            style57
```

and my problem is I dont how the achieve a query that will output

```
products.name       style.name
    sample1           style1
    sample1           style2
    sample1           style3
```

Comment: if you remove `schools.id = 57` from your query then you will get the expected output. Is there any specific reason of that `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Your example data doesn't match your result. You probably need to rearrange the order of joins, strating with `schools`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to delete the `Where schools.id = 75`

```
SELECT from prodcuts.name, style.name
FROM school_products
LEFT JOIN products on school_products.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN schools on school_products.school_id = schools.id
LEFT JOIN styles on school_products.school_id = styles.schools_id
```

Comment: I cant cuz every school has its own style

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem:

```
SELECT p.name Product, s.name Style
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_style ps 
ON ps.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN style s
ON s.id = ps.style_id
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Product  Style
----------------
sample1  style1
sample1  style2
sample1  style3
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0460c/3

Answer (score -1):

select a.name, b.name 
from products a 
join style b
on a.id=b.id

I think this should do the work